# Error "El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres..." con NuGet c# VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Instale un Package "NuGet" de un proyecto X (las DLL) en Mi proyecto Actual, he corregido los errores, ambigüedades y definiciones necesarias, pero al final al ejecutar me sale 2 errores, los cuales dicen: **error CS0246: El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'xxxxxxxx' no se encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)**.  Sin embargo reviso en las referencias y si están las que ha puesto en Nuget.

Este error me sale cuando las utilizo de la siguiente forma en el código: **xxxxxxxx.ModuleBase baseModule = new xxxxxxxx.ModuleBase();**
Donde xxxxxxxx es la referencia instalada por el NuGet.  Si lo utilizo como using me funciona, **pero no lo puedo usar** porque tendría muchos conflictos con mi proyecto actual. Otra cosa, al compilar o depurar, el error solo sale en la ventana de salida, en la ventana de Lista de Errores **no** sale.

Alguien sabe que se podría hacer?

Comment: Cuando dices: "El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'xxxxxxxx'", ¿las "xxxxxxxx" son librerías que son públicas o internas de tu empresa?

Comment: Hola, son internas de la empresa, las que deje en el package NuGet, estos paquetes los estoy dejando en un servidor de NugGets Local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualice versión de VS2017, reinicie todo y listo!
https://www.visualstudio.com/es-es/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.5.3

Específicamente este punto:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160594/migrating-from-vs2017-154-to-155-causes-cs026-the.html